# Can't get an interrupt at compare match of PWM Timer on STM32f103

Tags: c, timer, stm32, interrupt, pwm

I need to get interrupt at compare match of PWM.
I am using STM32CubeIDE 1.6.1, STM32Cube FW_F1 V1.8.3
even tried LL library instead of HAL inside `\STM32Cube\Repository\STM32Cube_FW_F1_V1.8.3\Projects\STM32F103RB-Nucleo\Examples_LL\TIM` directory but no luck!
I commented everything I tried before but didn't get the result I wanted.
I uploaded the logic analyzer result at the end.
thank you for your help.
[Logic analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXpxX.png)

in tim.c:

```
/* TIM4 init function */
void MX_TIM4_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 1 */
  htim4.Instance = TIM4;
  htim4.Init.Prescaler = 6400;
  htim4.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim4.Init.Period = 100;
  htim4.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim4.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim4, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim4, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim4, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim4);

}
```

in main.c:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 25);
  //HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim4);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_4);

/* USER CODE END 2 */
.
.
.

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(TEST_GPIO_Port, TEST_Pin);
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedHalfCpltCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(TEST_GPIO_Port, TEST_Pin);
}


void HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(TEST_GPIO_Port, TEST_Pin);
}

void HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedHalfCpltCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(TEST_GPIO_Port, TEST_Pin);
}


/* USER CODE END 4 */
```

in stm32f1xx_it.c:

```
void TIM4_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_IRQn 0 */
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(TEST_GPIO_Port, TEST_Pin);

//  /* Check whether CC4 interrupt is pending */
//  if (LL_TIM_IsActiveFlag_CC4(TIM4) == 1)
//  {
//      /* Clear the update interrupt flag*/
//      LL_TIM_ClearFlag_CC4(TIM4);
//
//      /* TIM4 capture/compare interrupt processing */
//      if (LL_TIM_GetCounter(TIM4) == LL_TIM_OC_GetCompareCH4(TIM4))
//      {
//
//          //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(TEST_GPIO_Port, TEST_Pin);
//      }
//  }

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim4);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_IRQn 1 */
}
```

[TIM4 Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ8Y1.png)

[TIM4 Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V1tg.png)

[Logic analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXpxX.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to images. Post the images inline.

Comment: Just a guess: I don't see the code that initializes the interrupt controller, registers `TIM4_IRQHandler` as the ISR for the given interrupt, or enables/disables interrupts in the CPU and/or interrupt controller

Comment: Are the interrupts enabled in NVIC?

Comment: @jwdonahue: because of my low reputation I can't post images inline.

Comment: @Craig Estey: inside "HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT" function, the "IT" part should enable the interrupte. As shown in logic analyser the Test pin is toggling inside "HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback" function. But at overflow of timer not the compare match!

Comment: @TRPh: yes, I enabled it inside CubeMX as shown in linked pictures.

Comment: @AmirSaeed you write "at overflow of timer not the compare match".  Your mention of overflow makes me think you are using an update interrupt, but your mention of compare makes me think you are using an output compare interrupt.  Which is it?  Could you have enabled the wrong interrupt?

Comment: The test pin on the logic analyzer trace is not sufficient to indicate interrupts are occurring _within_ the processor. And, the posted code does _not_ show that `TIM4_IRQHandler` has been registered as the ISR. There would need to be some call to the API that passes the _address_ of your ISR handler function to attach it to the interrupt.

Comment: Thank you guys for the tips, I have to try what you suggested and I will inform you the results.